# Using R to COUNT() and GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT x)

Tags: r

I'm analysing my web-server logs with R:

```
data = read.table("/path/to/log", sep=" ")
```

These logs include the end users IP address and USER_ID (once logged in).

I'm looking for users who are more active than usual, or use more IP addresses than usual.

I can currently get R to group and count the records by USER_ID:

```
counts <- ddply(data, .(data$user_id), nrow);
names(counts) <- c("user_id", "freq");
print(counts[order(counts$freq),c(2,1)], row.names = FALSE);

freq  user_id
   1    10171
  40     7433
  94      210
 102     2043
```

But I'd also like to add the equivalent of a GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IP), as seen in SQL, where I can see a list of distinct IP addresses for that user as well.

```
freq  user_id  ips
   1    10171  192.168.0.1
  40     7433  192.168.0.5,192.168.0.2
  94      210  192.168.0.9
 102     2043  192.168.0.1,192.168.0.3,192.168.0.8
```

In SQL, it would look something like:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    COUNT(id) AS freq,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ip SEPARATOR ",") AS ips
FROM
    log_table
GROUP BY
    user_id
ORDER BY
    freq ASC;
```

This might be possible with the aggregate() function, but I've not figured out how at the moment.

Comment: Definitely would recommend an R solution, but if you are experienced in SQL be sure to check out the `SQLDF` package to run sql queries on your dataframe.

Comment: FYI it is `sqldf` package

Comment: Thanks @NBATrends, good to know that `sqldf` exists, this time the solutions suggested below worked very well, but I can imagine this might help in the future (I am more familiar with SQL after all).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `data.table` we could do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[ , .N , by = user_id]
```

Note that in `data.table`, this counting operation has been optimized for speed since it is so common ([see benchmarks](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1251) and remember to check your `verbose` output for helpful diagnostics).

For the latter, this will work:

```
data[ , paste(unique(ip), collapse = ","), by = user_id]
```

To get both at once:

```
data[ , .(freq = .N, ips = paste(unique(ip), collapse = ",")),
     by = user_id]
```

If you wanted to sort it by frequency to find who the "biggest culprits" are:

```
data[ , .(freq = .N, ips = paste(unique(ip), collapse = ",")),
     by = user_id][order(-freq)]
```

depending on your use case, you might also consider aggregating `ip` to a list column instead of combining them.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelChirico that does seem to work very well. I'm also looking at the suggestion from akrun, and will see how well they compare (I've got about 1.5GB of gzipped logs to process, and should make up some tests).

Comment: Thanks again @MichaelChirico, I got this working and I also managed to tweak it for some similar queries. But just to note for anyone else reading this, the `dplyr` solution from @akrun also works (I'm just less familiar with that package).

Answer (score 9):

We can we `dplyr`.  We group by 'user_id' and then get the 'freq' as the number of rows (`n()`) and 'ips' as the `paste(unique(ip), collapse=', ')` (or we use `toString` as a wrapper).

```
library(dplyr) 
data %>%
    group_by(user_id) %>%
    summarise(freq= n(), ips= toString(unique(ip)))
    #not sure we wanted the nrow or `length`  of `unique` 'ip'
    #if the latter is the case
    #summarise(freq=n_distinct(ip), ips = toString(unique(ip)))
```

---

If we want a `base R` solution

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(ip~user_id, data,
    FUN= function(x) c(freq= length(unique(ip)), ips=toString(unique(ip))))
```

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but with a small number of records that the results look about right, but when there are over 10 results it says "Variables not shown: ips (chr)"?

Comment: @CraigFrancis It is an attribute of `tbl_df`.   THe variables are acutally there.  You can convert it to `data.frame` and check.  i.e. `res %>% as.data.frame` or just check `str(res)`

Comment: Thanks... well that's going to keep my computer busy for a minute or two (there are a lot of records) ... I'm going to have a play with this a bit more, and the other suggestions now.

Comment: first line of `toString.default`: `paste(x, collapse = ",")` :p

Comment: Thanks @akrun, this has been very helpful. Personally I found the solution from @MichaelChirico a bit easier for me to understand, with the data I'm using (more so editing for some other queries), so I'll be accepting their answer, but your `dplyr` solution works just as well, and I'm glad to see there is more than one correct answer (I didn't get the `do.call` solution working though, so I'll look at that again in a bit).